# Stitching animation in geometry nodes

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm struggling through learning geometry nodes and have run into an issue.
I'm trying to animate stitching instanced on a curve. I thought I could just use the "trim curve" node to do the animation, but it keeps shifting the positions of the stitches that have already appeared.
I've gotten this far combining different tutorials together.
[image: wiggly stitching]
Also, since I'm just animating the main path of the stitch, the instances just pop on (the animation is a lot slower that the example I've posted here so it will be very noticeable).
So my question is kind of two-fold -- is there a way to have the instances animate on as they appear on my path and not wiggle around while the rest of the curve is animating on?
Here's a link to the .blend: [Stitches](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tu3jk54rgeldzyk/Stitching%20Test.blend?dl=0)
If anybody has an idea of what I can do, I would totally appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: To fix the shifting try Resampling the curve before the Trim, and change the Curve to Points from Length to Evaluated. - - - - - - - 

Resample Curve (length or count) > Trim Curve > Curve to points (Evaluated)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a substantially different method from [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277036/35559), it's posted as a separate answer.

You say in commentary that you want a sweep animation through each stitch. To achieve this, rather than trimming the path on which the stitches are instanced, we can trim the stitch-splines, collectively.

This group will trim a multi-spline curve (splines ordered by index,) at its *accumulated* length:

[image]

(To my mind, this is what *Trim Curve* should have been in the first place; the node we've actually got should be called something more like *Trim Spline*.)

With this group, we can trim a realized, multi-spline stitch-curve as a whole, in place,and key-frame the accumulated trim 'End Length':

[image]

After which, there turns out to be a bit of deletion to do, to prevent the caps of 0-length splines appearing in the mesh result:

[image]

And then we have capped, swept stitches.

[image]

[image]

If you want very nicely rounded caps on the stitches for extreme close-ups, I *think* that's a bit more work, and merits another question.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this node setup?

[image]

I added a switch geometry node, so you can see the difference between both setups:

[image]

Comment: Aaarggh! :D I suspect this is a nice answer, but I can't tell! (.gifs too restricted for resolution, here)  Could you maybe add a .png of your tree arranged to show the contrast between your methods, and/or a one-sentence potted description of the difference?

Comment: i am very sorry, i forgot to paste the node setup. The text was there :D but no image. I added it.

Comment: Ahh! .. OK .. you're contrasting the native points of the curve, with _Curve to Points_. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks so much. It's working almost perfectly, but I'm still getting the stitch that's being added in a wonky place. I think I'm going to simplify this a little bit and instead of trimming the curves, see if I can just add a build modifier after the Geo Node modifier and see if I can have it build on that way.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with trimming the curve is that it will always be resampled. The end points of the curve *must* be at its ends. If the trim puts the end between previously sampled points, then there will be a visible adjustment.

A way to avoid this might be to sample the curve at the desired interval, leave it alone, and then animate the instancing of the stitches by the index of the (fixed) samples:

[image]

.. which can also handle (un-trimmable) cyclic splines or meshes..

[image]

Comment: Dang. That looks great! Question is, is there a way to animate each stitch because I'm going to be doing a lot macro shots before I cut to the wide. And it will be a lot slower, so it will be obvious when the stitch just pops on.
But seriously, I wish I could get a handle on Geometry Nodes like y'all have. My brain just doesn't work that way, I think. Thanks again everybody!

Comment: OK, @TheZFT, have posted another answer.